# Non modal dialog has to appear as modal window

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I can  show my custom NSWindowController as modal window by code:

```
TSAppDelegate* appDelegate = (TSAppDelegate*) [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSWindow* mainWindow = appDelegate.window; 

[NSApp beginSheet: [self window]
   modalForWindow: mainWindow
    modalDelegate: NULL
   didEndSelector: NULL
      contextInfo: NULL];
int acceptedModal = (int)[NSApp runModalForWindow: [self window]];
[NSApp endSheet: [self window]];
[[self window] close];
```

It works. But I need non modal window. It has to appear as modal (see pic) and be NON MODAL.

[image]

I tried

```
TSAppDelegate* appDelegate = (TSAppDelegate*) [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSWindow* mainWindow = appDelegate.window; 

[[self window] setParentWindow: mainWindow];
```

or

```
[mainWindow addChildWindow: [self window] ordered: NSWindowAbove];
```

It works as non modal but appears as normal popup window.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you just want a window to come down over your view but not be modal.

Rather than use a sheet, you could just use a separate view that you animate into and out of position.

You'll have to do some work yourself: setting the correct position, animating the view, responding to events, etc.